Reentrancy Logic: Where we already set the user balance to 0 on failed withdrawal
sorry, I am new, but anyway.
This is the Ethereum documentation that I’m referencing.
contract NoLongerAVictim {
    function withdraw() external {
        uint256 amount = balances[msg.sender];
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call.value(amount)("");
        require(success);
    }
}

So, if msg.sender.call{value: amount}(""); failed, but we already set balances[msg.sender] = 0, so how in this case user can repeat withdrawal if their balance already 0 but actually not, because it's just transaction failed.
Or, have they really demonstrated a bad example?
GPT’s answer is:

"You’re absolutely right! If the msg.sender.call{value: amount}(""); fails after we’ve reset the user’s balance to 0, the Ether remains in the contract, but the user can no longer withdraw it since their balance is effectively lost in the mapping. This is a critical bug in the design.


To fix this issue, we need to only update the user’s balance after the Ether transfer succeeds."

 forgot about reentrancy attack

The answer given by ChatGPT is incorrect because if the call to msg.sender.call.value(amount)("") fails, the state change setting balances[msg.sender] to 0 would be rolled back, as the function execution would revert entirely.

thanks. but in solidity docs wasn't written that .call works like revertion, as it was mentioned for .transfer.

Actually, .call returns a boolean value indicating success or failure. Since the withdraw() function checks this in the last line using require(success), if .call fails, require(success) will cause the function execution to revert entirely.
